# Google sign in session for websites

Tags: angular

I managed create a google sign in with the google developers tutorial. But sadly after the user logs in and all his credentials are log able in the console, i dont know how to handle his session to show his information in a user profile. The user gets signed in, his information is successfully written in the database and is saved in a userDataService. I want to show his informations on a profile like that:

**personaldata-profile.component.html:**

```
<p>Name: <br>...{{userDataService.displayName}}</p>
```

**personaldata-profile.components.ts:**

```
export class PersonalDataProfileComponent 
{ 
  constructor( public userDataService: UserDataService, private router: ActivatedRoute) 
  { 
  } 
}
```

And the **login.components.ts**

```
appStart = function () { 
  gapi.load('auth2', this.initSigninV2);
};

initSigninV2 = function () {
  this.auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
  client_id: '..........apps.googleusercontent.com',scope: 'profile'
}); 

public googleInit() {
  gapi.load('auth2', () => {
    this.auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
      client_id: '.......apps.googleusercontent.com',
      cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin',
      scope: 'profile email'            
    });             

    this.attachSignin(document.getElementById('googleBtn'));
  });
} 

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.googleInit();
}

public attachSignin(element) {
  this.googleUser
  this.auth2.attachClickHandler(element, {},(googleUser) => {
    const profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
    console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
    console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail());
    this.userDataService.googleUserId = profile.getId();
    this.userDataService.displayName = profile.getName();
    this.userDataService.familyName = profile.getFamilyName();
    this.userDataService.givenName = profile.getGivenName();
    this.userDataService.email = profile.getEmail();
    this.userDataService.imageUrl = profile.getImageUrl();
    this.userDataService.createUser();
    this.userDataService.redirect();
  }, 
  (error) => {
    alert(JSON.stringify(error, undefined, 2));
  });
}
```

I logged a lot and found out, that the userDataService object is empty at my profile page. But during `redirect()` the userDataService object is not empty at my profile page.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please read [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: Thank you, i made a mistake there.